# Simple inequalities

Tags: inequality

Suppose $l,t\in[0,1]$ and $l+t\leq1$ I want to prove $1+l+t>6lt$. When $t=0$ or $l=0$, it is trivial, so I started with $l,t\neq0$ but I couldn't reach anywhere. I don't have time to write in detail what I have already tried, but I tried to manipulate $(l-t)^2$ mostly. Anyway, if anyone help me with the proof that would be great. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM,  $4lt \le (l+t)^2\le 1$.

Similarly, $2 lt \le 2\sqrt{lt} \le l+t$.  Add these... and note equality is not possible for all the inequalities used simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If $l+t=a$ then $lt\le\frac{1}{4}a^2$ and we have
$$6lt-(l+t)\le{\textstyle\frac{3}{2}}a^2-a={\textstyle\frac{3}{2}}a(a-{\textstyle\frac{2}{3}})\ .$$
By sketching a graph it is easy to see that for $0\le a\le1$ the right hand side is at most $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is possible to state it as a optimization problem:

$$\min 1+l+t-6lt$$
$$s.t.$$
$$ l+t\leq 1$$
$$0\leq l\leq1$$
$$0\leq t\leq1$$

Which have a global minimum at $(l,t)=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ then $$1+l+t-6lt\geq1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-2\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}>0$$

Hope it helps